# Creating a Sidebar in ember JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ember.js

I have this example :
http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/04/17/slide-and-push-menus/

i want to push this into a template handle bar in EMBER js

What i did was

### Index.HTML

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">

I PUT ALL THE DIV SECTION IN THE INDEX.HTML EXAMPLE
</script>
```

### I ADDED THOSE JS

```
  <script src="js/libs/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/handlebars-1.1.2.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/ember-1.6.1.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  <script src="tests/classie.js"></script>
  <script src="tests/modernizr.custom.js"></script>
```

I run the file and when i click on the button's nothing happends. But if i remove the DIV section out of the HANDLEBARS it works...

Thanks
S

Answer (score 2):

When the code to initialize the sidebar is executed, the template isn't rendered yet. So the selectors won't find the element and the onclick function can't be binded to the button. In the view there is a 
didInsertElement event that is called once the template is rendered. Wrap the code to initialize the sidebar into a init() function:

```
function sidebarInit(){
   var menuLeft = document.getElementById( 'cbp-spmenu-s1' ),
        menuRight = document.getElementById( 'cbp-spmenu-s2' ),
        menuTop = document.getElementById( 'cbp-spmenu-s3' ),
    ...
    if( button !== 'showRightPush' ) {
        classie.toggle( showRightPush, 'disabled' );
    }
  }
```

and call it from your view.

```
   App.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
      didInsertElement : function(){
        this._super();
        sidebarInit();             
      }
    });
```

Comment: thanks but can u please tell me what u mean by //classie.js init() call here? sorry am a bit noob for the moment :P

Comment: I thought that the sidebar code was in that file but I was wrong. I'll modify my answer.

Comment: Beast :) thanks mate i tweaked it a bit got it as i want.. But i am now thinking on something better haha :P:P thanks